# How to include scripts with node/express/jade?

Tags: node.js, pug, mean, script-tag

I am building a MEAN stack application using Jade but I can't get any of my script tag links to work. The link tags work fine. I have tried absolute and relative links and about 5 other solutions that were posted on questions (most of them are a few years old) here on stack overflow but none of them have worked.

Here is the relevant code in my project:

(header.jade)

```
    link(href='libraries/normalize-css/normalize.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
    link(href='custom.css', rel='stylesheet')
    script(src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.min.js')
    script(src='/js/app.js')
```

(an example of where I want to use angular)

```
extends userBase
block vars
    - var title = 'Login'
block body
    h1.love love love
    div(ng-controller='ChoiceCtrl')
        form(method="post", role="form", style="width:90%; margin: 5px auto;", class="form-horizontal")
            input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=csrfToken)
            div.form-group
                label(for="question") Ask your question:
                input(type="text", name="question", required=true, class="form-control", id="question", placeholder='Which team will win the super bowl this year...?')
                br
            ul.list-group
                li.list-group-item(ng-repeat="choice in choices")
                    span {{ 2+2 }}
            div.form-group
                label(for="responses") Choose Response Options:
                .input-group
                    input(type="text", name="response", class="form-control", id="responses", ng-model='choiceBody')
                    span.input-group-btn
                        input(type="submit", class='btn btn-primary', value='Add', ng-click='addChoice()')
            input(type="submit", class='btn btn-primary', value='Create Poll')
```

Also, in the server.js file the routing for static files works fine so I am not sure where the problem is.

The rest of the code is here on github: https://github.com/gwenf/votenow

Comment: How are they "not working"?  Are you getting 404s for those scripts in the network panel?  Can you navigate to the actual location of the script on your server?

Comment: it's a status code 500

Comment: What does your server console say then?  Are you getting a stack trace?  500 is server error.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…0d%20(https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)
createPoll:7

Comment: GET https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/angular.min.js

Comment: Those two fields have red x's next to them in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was forgetting to include a script tag for angular's ui-router. I put the script tag after the one for angular:

```
link(href='libraries/normalize-css/normalize.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='custom.css', rel='stylesheet')
script(src='libraries/angular/angular.js')
script(src='libraries/angular-ui-router/angular-ui-router.js')
script(src='/js/app.js')
```

and then I included it in my app.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router']);
```